# python run cvs update

Tags: python, linux, cvs

I must make a script to run unittests. This script is written in python and it runs on a Linux computer.

It must check the cvs repository, and if a change is detected, the script tries to update the local cvs repository, and after it runs the unittests and generates a report for the dev team.

The script at the beginning is setting the `CVSROOT` to the correct value.
I'm setting the CVSROOT with :

```
os.environ["CVSROOT"] = ':ext:user@server:/cvsdir'
```

When I'm launching this script, I have a problem with the `cvs update`:

```
cvs [update aborted]: received broken pipe signal
cvs [update aborted]: write error
```

the command line who launches the `cvs update` is:

```
os.popen("cvs update -d")
```

and I tried

```
os.popen("cvs update")
```

When i run in a terminal "cvs update" or "cvs update -d", the update runs without problem.

My question is, why i have this "update aborted" and how can i fix it ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your question? How can we help?

Comment: have you tried jenkins?

Comment: @Foo Bar User, No i didn't try tu use jenkins in this case, because actually the script must be run on the computer of the developer, but in the future srpints we will integrate this in the unit test server

Comment: ok i just thought you are trying to reinvent the wheel well if there's a reason its a different case.

Comment: I resolve my problem, I must write it like that : `os.popen("cvs update -d").readlines()` . But i don't understand, why i must to write with the method readlines.